# unable to open my another activity from previous activity

Tags: android, validation, android-intent, android-activity

```
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105): Process: com.rtminds.patientinformationsystem, PID: 2105
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rtminds.patientinformationsystem/com.rtminds.patientinformationsystem.AddDoctor}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105):     at com.rtminds.patientinformationsystem.AddDoctor.onCreate(AddDoctor.java:76)
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
12-12 02:51:14.438: E/AndroidRuntime(2105):     ... 11 more

```
public class Add_Details extends Activity {

ImageButton addDoctor_img, addPatient_img, viewPatient_img;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__details);

    addDoctor_img = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addDoctor_detils);
    addPatient_img = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addPatient_detils);
    viewPatient_img = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.viewPatient_detils);

    configureImageButton();
}

public void configureImageButton() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        // add doctor details...
        addDoctor_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent add_doc = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        AddDoctor.class);
                startActivity(add_doc);
                finish();

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public class AddDoctor extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText f_name_doc, l_name_doc, suffix_doc, email_doc, password_doc,
        confirm_doc, mob_doc, dob_doc, age_doc, specility_doc, city_doc;
RadioGroup gender;
RadioButton male_doc, female_doc;
Button add_doc;
ImageButton cal_dob;
private Calendar cal;
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;
static String URL = OpdLogin.URL;
public static final String url_adddoc = URL + "doctorregistration";
HttpClient client;
String text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_doctor);

    f_name_doc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.f_name_doc);
    l_name_doc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.l_name_doc);
    suffix_doc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.suffix_doc);
    email_doc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_doc);
    password_doc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_doc);
    confirm_doc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirm_doc);
    mob_doc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mob_doc);
    dob_doc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dob_doc);
    age_doc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age_doc);
    specility_doc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.specility_doc);
    city_doc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.city_doc);
 <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/addDoctor_detils"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/AddDoctor"
                android:onClick="configureImageButton"
                android:padding="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/doctor_add" />
 <activity
        android:name=".AddDoctor"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_doctor" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.rtminds.patientinformationsystem.AddDoctor" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to replace getApplicationContext() to Add_Details.this

Comment: The exception is happening in the `AddDoctor` Activity.

Comment: Which line is this? AddDoctor.onCreate(AddDoctor.java:76)